# Display status message in facebook app development

Tags: php, facebook

im trying to display a users status messages (5 of them for now) by using the graph api.

im using the following path:

```
me?fields=statuses.limit(5).fields(message)
```

however thsi gives me the following error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in site/index.php on line 30

now im guessing this is something to do with the api path, because if i try

```
$status_info = $facebook->api('me/friends');
```

i can print out anything from that array without any problems, can anyone help me?

thanks.

var_dump for status_info is:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(15) "********" ["statuses"]=> array(2) { ["data"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(61) "status message 1 here......."
```

and it continues with other results.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($status_info)` ?

Comment: just updated the original post with the var dump.

Comment: see my answer. You need to use `$status_info["statuses"]['data']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this;

```
foreach($status_info["statuses"]['data'] as $key => $value) {
....
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  will choose as correct answer when time has elapsed to do so.